# Jquery if one of the two checkboxes is checked in list.

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form which contains two lists of `radio` checkboxes.

I need a validation check wether one checkbox is checked in either list. 
To illustrate:

```
   <form>
    <input type="radio" name="1">
    <input type="radio" name="1">

    <input type="radio" name="2">
    <input type="radio" name="2">

    <button type="submit"></button>
    </form>
```

so when the form submits, it needs to check wether a checkbox is checked in 'name1' or in 'name2' or in both. If not,it should not let the request through, and give an error message: "This is required". I tried doing this in Jquery with the following code:

```
$("#submit").on("click",function(){
      if ($("input[name*='name1']:checked") || $("input[name*='name2']:checked")) {
        $("form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        $('#segmentError').toggle();

        if($("#Error").is(':visible')) {
          $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top});
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
```

However, now it won't let the request through whatsoever. I'm not that good with JQuery, so I hope one of you can help me with this problem.

Comment: Looks like an issue about fundamental programming and jQuery understanding: Both are not checked if both check states return `false`. And there is no need to bind to the same event within that event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this hook to the `submit` event of the form and check the length of the `:checked` radio buttons. You can then call `preventDefault()` on the event to stop the submission, if needed:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!$('input[name="name1"]:checked').length && !$('input[name="name2"]:checked').length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#segmentError').toggle();
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Use the `&&` operator instead the `||` because only one of them must be checked, not the both.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things I see wrong in your snippet.

1. You are using #submit but the submit button does not have an id set
2. You are using name = 'name1' in your javascript but the name in the HTML is name="1" (name1 vs 1). So they do not match.

Here is a sample JSFiddle to show you how to check whether each of the pairs of checkboxes is checked.

https://jsfiddle.net/bwahhpnd/

Basically you can use:

```
$("input[name='1']:checked").length
```

To see if any of the inputs are checked (if length is 0 none is checked).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val()) {
    $('form').submit();
  } else {
    $('.error-container').text('This is required');
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="error-container"></p>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="1">
  <input type="radio" name="1">
  <input type="radio" name="2">
  <input type="radio" name="2">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Four things:

Your selector has an error, it's looking for names like "name1" and not names like "1": `$("input[name*='1']:checked").length > 0 || $("input[name*='2']:checked")).length > 0` Also, you need to check how many elements were grabbed with the `.length` check

The other is that your submit button does not have `id="submit"` on it and so the click event is not bound.

Finally, you need to bind prevent default earlier:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });

$("#submit").on("click",function(){
console.log("clicky");
console.log($("input[name*='1']:checked"));
      if ($("input[name*='1']:checked").length > 0 || $("input[name*='2']:checked").length > 0) {
      console.log('found checked');

        $('#segmentError').toggle();

        if($("#Error").is(':visible')) {
          $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top});
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/msLrc2dm/1/

Answer (score 1):

As said in the other answers...

fixed and put it into a working fiddle

```
$("input[name='name1']").is(':checked')
```

use the ".is(':checked') to test if selected

https://jsfiddle.net/zjhtye8c/2/

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code I see a couple of issues you need to update in order to make it work:

**1. Assign an `id` to the submit button** in order to reference it later in jQuery:

```
<button id="submit" type="submit"></button>
```

**2. Update the `if` clause** as follows:

```
if ( $("input[name='1']:checked").val() && $("input[name='2']:checked").val() )
```

#### Working snippet

```js
$("#submit").on("click", function() {

  if ($("input[name='1']:checked").val() && $("input[name='2']:checked").val()) {
    alert("input checked in list 1 and input checked in list 2");
  } else {
    alert("some checked radio buttons are missing")
  }

  return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="1">
  <input type="radio" name="1">

  <input type="radio" name="2">
  <input type="radio" name="2">

  <button id="submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can find a working fiddle of your code with my updates here: https://jsfiddle.net/1jqgno2b/